# Textbooks for CELI exams

Tags: grammar, resources

Is there any good textbook for:

- grammar revision for the CELI exam (from level A1 to C2)
- writing part (for text writing) preparation with tips etc.  (exams CELI 4 and CELI 5)
- general preparation (books with past exams CELI 4 and CELI 5)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie mille, Charo.

Answer (score 4):

The textbooks I know are those ones from the series [*Come prepararsi all'esame del CELI*](http://www.guerra-edizioni.com/books/index.cfm?node=0,1,22,1006,168) from Guerra Edizioni. I have seen them in some Barcelona libraries. These are books that propose you exercises with the same format of the different parts of the exam. They come with CDs that allow you to practice the listening part of the exam. They also include the transcriptions of all the recorded material and the solution keys to all the exercises.